Unable to get PYQT5 headless print HTML to PDF work as Azure function App with Linux App service plan
I have a code something like below to print HTML as PDF using PyQt5 library. This code works fine when tested via VS code function core tools however when it is deployed as azure function app I get an error - QT platform plugin could not be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix.
When i set os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen" i get a different error:
WebEngineContext used before QTWebEngine::Initialize()
Is there any way to run it as a function app on Azure App service environment using PyQt5?
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import os
import sys
import tempfile
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize

# Set the environment variable for Qt

class PDFGenerator:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
        # os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM"] = "offscreen"
        self.loader.setZoomFactor(1)
        self.layout = QPageLayout()
        self.layout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4Extra))
        self.layout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)
        self.loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(self.on_pdf_printed)
        self.loader.loadFinished.connect(self.emit_pdf)
        self.load_url()

    def load_url(self):
        self.loader.load(QtCore.QUrl(self.url))

    def emit_pdf(self):
        output_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'output.pdf')
        self.loader.page().printToPdf(output_path, self.layout)

    def on_pdf_printed(self, path, success):
        if success:
            logging.info(f"PDF saved to {path}")
        else:
            logging.error("Failed to save PDF")
        self.app.quit()

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
     # Hardcoded URL
     url = "https://www.example.com"

     pdf_generator = PDFGenerator(url)
     pdf_generator.app.exec_()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error: {e}", status_code=500)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"PDF generation completed for {url}", status_code=200)

Deployed the function app to azure but it failed to execute with QT initialization failure.

I'm not completely sure you can do that in a completely headless mode (and it seems that making azure work fine with Qt programs isn't that immediate), but note that in any case it makes little point in using QWebEngineView, since no view would be actually shown. Just use QWebEnginePage.

@musicamante thank you for the response and reference article

Thanks musicamante for the comment. Indeed, you can use QWebEnginePage if you wish to execute your code in Function App.
I have modified your code wherein I am using QWebEnginePage.
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import os
import sys
import tempfile
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM'] = 'offscreen'
os.environ['QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS'] = '--no-sandbox'

class PDFGenerator(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url
        self.output_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "output.pdf")
        self.layout = QPageLayout()
        self.layout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4Extra))
        self.layout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)
        self.loop = QEventLoop()

        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)
        logging.info(f"Loading URL: {self.url}")
        self.load(QUrl(self.url))  

    def on_load_finished(self, success):
        if success:
            logging.info(f"Page loaded successfully: {self.url}")
            logging.info("Starting PDF generation...")
            try:
                self.printToPdf(self.on_pdf_generated, self.layout)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error during PDF generation: {e}", exc_info=True)
                self.loop.quit()
        else:
            logging.error(f"Failed to load the page: {self.url}")
            self.loop.quit()

    def on_pdf_generated(self, pdf_content):
        try:
            with open(self.output_path, "wb") as f:
                f.write(pdf_content)
            logging.info(f"PDF successfully saved to: {self.output_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error saving PDF: {e}", exc_info=True)
        finally:
            self.loop.quit()

    def generate(self):
        self.loop.exec_()  
        return self.output_path

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        url = "https://www.wikipedia.org/" 
        logging.info(f"Initializing PDF generation for URL: {url}")
        
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        pdf_generator = PDFGenerator(url)
        pdf_path = pdf_generator.generate()
        
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"PDF successfully generated and saved at {pdf_path}",
            status_code=200
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error: {e}", exc_info=True)
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Error: {e}", status_code=500)

I have below modules in requirements.txt file.
azure-functions
PyQt5
qtgui
PyQtWebEngine

I have deployed this code in Function App which is in App Service plan and also have added QT_QPA_PLATFORM and QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS in environment variable.

